# Is setting a class as Internal sufficient on a class that can decrypt your password

Tags: c#, encryption

Below is a stripped down version of an Encryption/Decryption class I found on the internet a while ago.

I have been using this to store a password in a config file in an encrypted format so that it can't be read by prying eyes. Then can be decrypted inapp to access a network resource.

I'm using this to prevent anyone reading the plain text password in any way e.g. a config file, passing it as a command line variable that would have to be in a scheduled task etc.

This is a Console app and one of the command line parameters allows the user to get the encrypted version of a string password they supply, there is no publicly accessible decrypt method.

Is setting the class as internal enough to prevent someone from being able to call the Decrypt method or reverse engineer an encrypted password, I'm guessing it will prevent anyone from making a reference to it and just calling the decrypt method but can I do anything else to harden the security?

I thought about passing the Key and Vector into the constructor from outside but wasn't sure if it would actually help improve the security if they were still in the same dll, if someone can get those bytes does it matter where they are being stored?

```
internal class SimpleAES
{
    private byte[] Key = { 1, 2, .. n };
    private byte[] Vector = { 1, 2, .. n };

    private ICryptoTransform EncryptorTransform, DecryptorTransform;
    private System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTFEncoder;

    public SimpleAES()
    {
        RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();
        EncryptorTransform = rm.CreateEncryptor(this.Key, this.Vector);
        DecryptorTransform = rm.CreateDecryptor(this.Key, this.Vector);
        UTFEncoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    }

    public string EncryptToString(string TextValue)
    {
        return ByteArrToString(Encrypt(TextValue));
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(string TextValue)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = UTFEncoder.GetBytes(TextValue);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, EncryptorTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();

        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] encrypted = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
        memoryStream.Read(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);

        cs.Close();
        memoryStream.Close();

        return encrypted;
    }

    public string DecryptString(string EncryptedString)
    {
        return Decrypt(StrToByteArray(EncryptedString));
    }

    public string Decrypt(byte[] EncryptedValue)
    {
        MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream decryptStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, DecryptorTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        decryptStream.Write(EncryptedValue, 0, EncryptedValue.Length);
        decryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        encryptedStream.Position = 0;
        Byte[] decryptedBytes = new Byte[encryptedStream.Length];
        encryptedStream.Read(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);
        encryptedStream.Close();

        return UTFEncoder.GetString(decryptedBytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fundamentally, your code still contains the key and IV. Those would be available to anyone using `ildasm` or similar tools. At that point, you have no secrets.

Comment: no. `internal` modifier doesnt do anything about security.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whatever accesibility you choose, be it `public`, `internal`, `private` or whatever else, has **absolutely nothing to do** with security. Your code does nothing else than *obscure* the value, but has not even a remote connection with true data security.

A potential attacker would take just a couple minutes to reveal the 'encrypted' value. The fundamental thing here is that the `Key` and `Vector` are **built-in to the software itself**, so once you get access to binaries, you get access to this information. Hence the whole thing is insecure *by design*.

---

*Recommended literature: [Bruce Schneier, Applied Cryptography](https://www.schneier.com/books/applied_cryptography/).*